# Can't toggle software keyboard in iOS Simulator 10.2 or 10.3

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appium-ios

[image]

I am using `ios simulator 10.3` and noticed that I can't toggle software keyboard anymore, and can't type anything. I downgraded to `ios simulator 10.2` but the same problem persists.

I was able to make it work by deleting `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` in `~/Library/Preference` but the problem again pops up when I restart my simulator. Can anyone help me to fix this issue or tell me when or why this `Toggle Software Keyboard` option is disabled ?

Comment: got this working?

Answer (score 30):

`Toggle Software Keyboard` is only available if `Connect Hardware Keyboard` is selected.

Comment: its also available for iPhone 12 emulator

Comment: Very helpful. Noticed that after setting the software keyboard, the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" can be unchecked to avoid inadvertently flipping back to the hardware keyboard.

Comment: that did the trick! they should remove the `Connect hardware keyboard` shortcut imo

Answer (score 15):

This should put it back (write this in terminal):

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ConnectHardwareKeyboard -bool YES
```

Comment: Omg, finally. I've had this issue for months and this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

For me `cmd + k` was not opening the keyboard in the `iPhone 8 plus` emulator. But when I used the same short key for the `iPhone 12 Pro Max` emulator the soft keyboard was opening.